# How to check if Handler has an active task?

Tags: java, android

If I have a `Handler handler = new Handler()` and run a delayed task for it `handler.postDelayed(xxx, xxx)`, is that possible to check has the `postDelayed()` was called or not?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> is that possible to check has the postDelayed() was called or not?

One quick fix, in method assign some `boolean` variable to true and then just perform checking.

Comment: is not safe... if 2 thread run this handler 
maby not working like charm :)

Answer (score 23):

There is no direct API to achieve this but you can do a work around for this by using the `sendEmptyMessage` function. Hope this will help.

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(some_integer);//Do this when you add the call back.
if(handler.hasMessages(some_integer))
handler.removeMessages(some_integer);//Do this after removing the call back.
```

Comment: hasMessages() always returns false in my code. Has this been confirmed to work?

Comment: Yes indeed handler.sendEmptyMessage(1); this will set an empty message in the handler so when you call if(handler.hasMessages(1)) this will return true. If you removed the message using removeMessages(1) then it will return false

Comment: hasMessages(1) still returns false for me immediately after issuing sendEmptyMessage(1). Have you used this code in an app?

Comment: Not working. To anyone reading this: Please use a boolean type variable instead to achieve this.

Answer (score 17):

Handler when posting a Runnable obtains the Message with "what" field == 0, so in theory you could call `hasMessages(0)`, but you cannot check if it has given pending Runnable - for example when posting r0 and r1 you cannot check if r0 is pending or not.

Comment: This is clever witty thought! Thankx

Answer (score 8):

`Handler.post()` is just a convenience wrapper method for `sendMessageDelayed()`, so if you wish to check whether a handler has a specific pending Runnable that is still actively running, or whether the `postDelayed()` was called with a specific Runnable, then try using the following class:

```
 public class HandlerWithID extends Handler {
     public HandlerWithID() {
         super();
     }

     public HandlerWithID(Looper looper) {
         super(looper);
     }

    public final boolean postDelayed (int runnableID, long delayMillis, Runnable r) {
        Message m = Message.obtain(this, r);
        m.what = runnableID;
        return  sendMessageDelayed(m, delayMillis);
    }

    public final boolean post(int runnableID, Runnable r) {
        return postDelayed(runnableID, 0, r);
    } 

    public final boolean hasActiveRunnable(int runnableID) {
        return hasMessages(runnableID);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set looper on constructor ?

Comment: @DimasLanjaka the parent Handler class already uses Looper.Main by default.  If you wish to set a custom Looper, then see the modified the code above.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
First, add a **class variable** *(not **local variable**)*.

**Step 2:**
Check the **handler** that if it is running or not using the variable.

```
    public MyClass{
    
    boolean isAlreadyDoing;
.
.
.
.
    
    if(!isAlreadyDoing){
        isAlreadyDoing=true;
        new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
        isAlreadyDoing=false;
         //Do task here
        }, delaytTime);
      }
    }
```